# Tag-synonymous suggestion conditions weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, tag-synonyms

The conditions state

> Users with more than 2500 reputation on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms.

I successfully suggested a "template-function" synonym for the "function-template" tag. Still I only have a total of 4 reputation on that tag. Something is going wrong here.

Comment: Where did you read that statement? On a related note, a [blank tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/joptionpane/info) says having a bronze badge in the tag is required whereas the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki) says a tag score of 100 is sufficient. A bronze badge requires 20 answers though. Which page is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yerp, I found the bug, there were a few actually.

My intention was always to require users to have a score of 5 or more on the tag to even propose a synonym, it was set to 0.

Then there was UI bug that was appending up a sentence incorrectly if the setting was 0.

Both will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: The synonym page currently says "Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms." I have +10 in the websphere-mq tag and cannot vote.  Tried in IE and Firefox with scripting enabled, yadda, yadda. Did you miss a bug or two? Is the explanatory text wrong?